# The effects of collapsing vs joining non-adjacent vertices on the chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

For any set $X$, let $[X]^2 = \big\{\{x,y\}: x\neq y \in X\big\}$.

Is there a finite, simple, undirected, connected graph $G=(V,E)$ with the following properties?

1. There is $\{v, w\}\in [V]^2\setminus E$ such that collapsing $v,w$ increases the chromatic number, but
2. for all $\{a, b\}\in [V]^2\setminus E$ we have $\chi((V,E)) = \chi((V, (E\cup\{a,b\})))$, that is, adding an edge connecting $a$ and $b$ does not increase the chromatic number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes,** such a graph does exist.  Let $G$ be obtained from the complete graph $K_{100}$ by adding two non-adjacent vertices $v$ and $w$ such that $|N_G(v)|=|N_G(w)|=50$ and $N_G(v) \cup N_G(w)=V(K_{100})$. Here, $N_G(v)$ denotes the set of vertices of $G$ which are adjacent to $v$. Then collapsing $v$ and $w$ in $G$ yields $K_{101}$, which increases the chromatic number.  On the other hand, it is easy to see that adding any edge to $G$ does not increase the chromatic number.

Comment: Here $50$ can be treated as a variable, whose smallest value seems to be $2$. Bigger values of $50$ have the advantage that you can add quite a few edges without increasing the chromatic number.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Indeed.  We can even allow $N_G(v)$ and $N_G(w)$ to intersect if we like.  Most values of $|N_G(v)|, |N_G(w)|$, and $|N_G(v) \cap N_G(w)|$ will give valid examples (this is basically a list colouring problem on $v$ and $w$).

Comment: Beautiful example, thanks @TonyHuynh!